# Creating an Item to be taken, then used latter in C# for a texted base-game

Tags: c#, text-based

I need to create an item that the player decides to take and then use at a later time.

Really I am looking for a command to open up a backpack that lists the items the player has collected. then the player can return to the previous state. This is for a text-based game.

I also need to know how to define an item I create, that can be used.

Comment: This looks like a very broad feature. Do you have any parts of this working already? (Accepting & parsing player input, calling methods based on those input commands, tracking your inventory list...) Each aspect of this could be asked as a separate question, so consider trying to focus on just the first aspect that's giving you trouble. If possible, include some code or description of how your game works so far, so we know what structure an answer needs to integrate into.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have working knowledge of C# and it sounds a little bit like you might be fishing for someone to just give you code that'll work here--but I'll give some broad-strokes advice and **pseudocode** in the hope that you're really just looking for a little direction. For simplicity, I'll assume you don't mean for the backpack to be another item the user could take or leave, but rather for the backpack to be equivalent to the player's inventory.

The first big task is figuring out how to represent the "item". There are two main approaches.

If all of your items all basically do the same thing (i.e., all of your items are food the player can eat, or weapons they can use), you could represent them with a struct or a compound data type like a dictionary. Either of these could hold string values like the name of the item, a longer description of it, and numeric values like how heavy or powerful a weapon is, or how many hit-points the food might heal.

```
struct Food {
   string name;
   string description;
   integer heals;
   integer weight;
};

struct Food banana = Food("banana", "a ripe banana", 10, 1);
```

If you're going to have items that do all kinds of different things, you probably want to write an item class of some sort that defines behavior all of your items should have, and write individual items that inherit the generic item and customize it.

```
class Item {
    string name;
    string description;
    integer weight;
};

class Food : Item {
    boolean edible = true;
    integer spoil_time = -1;
    integer max_heal;

    integer heals(){
        if(spoil_time == 0){
            return -max_heal;
        } else {
            return max_heal;
        }
    }

    void age(){
        if(spoil_time > 0){
            spoil_time--;
            if(spoil_time == 0){
                print("The "+name+" begins to stink.");
                description = description + " (spoiled)";
            }
        }
    }     
};

class Banana : Food {
    string name = "banana";
    string description = "a banana";
    integer max_heal = 10;
    integer spoil_time = 600;
    boolean edible = false;

    void peel(){
        print("You peel the banana.");
        edible = true;
    }
}
```

Regardless of whether you represent the items as a data type or a class, you can store the items in a "list" type. You'll have one at least one list for the player's inventory. If you want the player to be able to "drop" an item and take it again later, you also want each "room" or "location" in your game to have its own inventory list.

You'll also need commands to work with these. Here are a few examples:

```
boolean eat(string what){
    foreach(item in player.inventory){
        if(item.name == what){
            if(item.edible){
                player.adjust_hp(item.heals());
                print("You eat "+item.description);
                player.inventory_weight -= item.weight;
                return true;
            } else {
                print("You can't eat that!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    print("Your stomach grumbles as you search in vain.");
    return false;
}

void inventory(){
    print("You open up the backpack and see:")
    foreach(item in player.inventory){
        print(item.description);
    }
}

boolean take(string what){
    foreach(item in player.inventory){
        if(item.name == what){
            integer new_weight = player.inventory_weight + item.weight;
            if( new_weight > player.max_inventory_weight ){
                player.inventory_weight = new_weight;
                print("You pick up "+item.description);
                return true;
            } else {
                print("You can't carry any more!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    print("There's no "+what+" to take.");
    return false;
}
```

If you'd like the player to be able to look at or inspect these items, you probably need to modify your existing look command to also check the player's inventory and possibly the room's inventory.